# What is a ContentProvider and what is it typically used for?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

i'm beginner in android development, need help regarding **ContentProvider**.

```
public class My Application extends  ContentProvider {}
```

Comment: You should start by googling for information. For example, you will find [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) from the official documentation.

Comment: @Pinkin S its like a gate inorder for other apps to gather/collect some information coming from your app `e.g. SQLite content`. Basically all the sensitive data are not accessible by default outside in your app so it is up to your own will whether to expose it using a ContentProvider.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. It will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A ContentProvider manages access to a structured set of data. It encapsulates the data and provide mechanisms for defining data security. ContentProvider is the standard interface that connects data in one process with code running in another process.

[image]

Kindly refer following links,

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html

and

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_content_providers.htm

Answer (score 5):

A content provider component supplies data from one application to others on request. one application cannot directly access (read/write) other application's data. Every application has its own id data directory and own protected memory area.
Content provider is the best way to share data across applications. Content provider is a set of data wrapped up in a custom API to read and write. Applications/Processes have to register themselves as a provider of data.
In simple language you can say content provider is a shared database which expose his properties and on there behalf of them other application can access and store the data as per the implementation privilege

Answer (score 2):

Content providers can help an application manage access to data stored by itself, stored by other apps, and provide a way to share data with other apps. They encapsulate the data, and provide mechanisms for defining data security. Content providers are the standard interface that connects data in one process with code running in another process. Implementing a content provider has many advantages. Most importantly you can configure a content provider to allow other applications to securely access and modify your app data.
It is not that they are used only to share data with other applications. You may still use them because they provide a nice abstraction, but you don’t have to necessarily share data with other apps. This abstraction allows you to make modifications to your application data storage implementation without affecting other existing applications that rely on access to your data

You can get more info from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).

Comment: Thq sm @ioCurator

Answer (score 1):

ContentProvider is mainly used for access data from one application to another application.

For example by using ContentProvider we can get phone contacts,call log from phone to our own application in android.we can also access data which are stored in (sqlite)databases.

Comment: Thq sm @sasikumar